# Move data from tables to another database scheduled

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi what is the most efficient way to move outdated data from one table to another database with exactly the same data structure.

I mean in the perfect world I would somehow just point out the tables and select which field or a query that evaluates if a row is out dated and needs to move?

It would minimize the work if some tables changes in the future.

Comment: please, be specific. what did you mean by Outdated?!

Answer (score 0):

If both databases are on one server, then `INSERT...SELECT...` is fine. If they are on separate servers, there are other options as described in the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190923.aspx). I suggest you read up on the alternatives, try to implement something and then come back with more specific questions.